# jQuery AJAX also send hidden fields on form change

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post, hidden

I've been searching for this all morning but didn't find anything that could help me. I couldn't figure this out with the manual...  I've never really written any jQuery or javaScript so please be gentle.

I was able to figure out how to update the database when the user leaves the input field. :) But I also want to send the hidden input fields.

Here is my form & script (the form elements have the same NAME as ID so for this example I left them out to keep things readable)

```
<form id="Form">
  <input id='idA01-01-2017' type='hidden' value="1234"/>
  <input id='idB01-01-2017' type='hidden' value="5678"/>

  <input id='fromA01-01-2017' type='text' value=""/>
  <input id='toA01-01-2017' type='text' value=""/>
  <input id='fromB01-01-2017' type='text' value=""/>
  <input id='toA01-01-2017' type='text' value=""/>
  <input id="checkA01-01-2017" type="checkbox" value="1">
  <input id="checkB01-01-2017" type="checkbox" value="1">
  <input id='suggestion01-01-2017' type='text' value=""/>
</form>


<script>
    $('input, select', $('#Form')).change(function(){
        var dataFields = $(this).attr('id')+$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataFields,
           dataType: "json",
           success: function() {}
        })
    });
</script>
```

-edit-
I'm very thankful to the help I got from Axel, but the script seemed to break my checkboxes.

The initial form was submit by `onChange="document.Form.submit()"` because of this I needed the hidden input fields before the checkboxes, to set the value in case the box was unchecked.

Now with the jQuery part this didn't work, so I removed the hidden fields and use the following script. As I'm completely new at jQuery there is probably a better way, but it seems to work alright.

```
    $('input, select', $('#Form')).change(function(){

    var FORMdata = {},

    // get current name
    currName = $(this).attr('name'),
    // extract the date
    sDate = currName.substr(currName.length - 10);

    //check if a checkbox is changed
    if (currName.indexOf("checker") >= 0 ){
       if($(this).is(":checked")) {
          FORMdata[currName] =  '1';
       } 
       else {
          FORMdata[currName] =  '0';
       }
    }else{
        // no checkbox was changed so it was a input field
        // add current field to data object
        FORMdata[currName] =  $(this).val();
        }

    $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: FORMdata,
            success: function() {
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want just submit your changed fields plus the related (identified by the ending of each name attribute) hidden ones, you can do something like this:

```
$('input, select').on('change, input', function(){
    var data = {},
        // get current name
        currName = $(this).attr('name'),
        // extract the date
        sDate = currName.substr(currName.length - 10);

    // add current field to data object
    data[currName] =  $(this).val();

    // loop over all hidden fields ending with the same 
    // identifier (date) add them to data
    $('#Form').find("input[type='hidden'][name$='"+ sDate+"']").each(function(){
        data[$(this).attr('name')] =  $(this).val();
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {}
    })
});
```

In case you want to send complete form - jQuery has a function for this: [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). You might also use the native method  [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FormData) which works in recent browsers:

```
// also use input event to handle pasting of data
$('input, select').on('change, input', function(){
    // jQuery way (strings only)
    var formData = $('#Form').serialize();
    // or native javascript (older browsers not supported)
    // var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("Form"));
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {}
    })
});
```

Comment: Nice this works, but sends the whole form, I just like to send the field that has changed plus the hidden fields. And yes I know that's why I added "(the form elements have the same NAME as ID so for this example I left them out to keep things readable)"

Comment: @needle I've updated my answer with a variant to send only changed plus hidden fields.

Comment: Am I correct that "$('input, select').on('change, input', function(){" also sends data to update.php before the user leaves the input field?

Comment: @needle yes, you are correct, in case you want to fire in case the user leaves the field, you can use the blur event.

Comment: Thanks this is so helpful! Something I should have mentioned is that the form is generated by PHP. For everyday of the month there are the same input fields with the day of the month added to the ID and NAME. So now I get the one changed value and then all the other hidden values for everyday of the month.  Here I have two lines to extract the date, but how do I add this to attr('name')  `code`  var temp = $(this).attr('name');
  var date = temp.substr(temp.length-10);

Comment: @needle I'm not sure if I get your question correct. The example above would add all hidden fields to each AJAX post, but you want only the ones with the corresponding date - to the one which changed - is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Because only one field is updated every time, It would be unnecessary to send all others. In the update.php I just leave all the empty ones out, but It would be cleaner if I could do that before they get past to update.php

Comment: @needle I have updated my answer one more time - next time try to specify your needs a bit better. The concept is the same as before, just the hidden field selector is modified and uses the 'ends with' syntax for the name attribute. Untested but it should work like this.