# How to pass a parameter to a modal form using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a razor page that displays a list of expenses for the Report selected. I have an "Add Expense" button on the page that brings up a modal. The modal is a partial View of the form. What i need to do is pass the ExpenseId to the modal. I can get the Id from the url like this

```
 @{ var expenseId = Request.Url.Segments[3]; }
```

the button currently looks like this

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#expenseModal_@expenseId" data-id="@expenseId" class="btn btn-primary" id="addExpenses">
                        Add Expense
                    </button>
```

There are a few things in this that i do not know if i even need them. I was trying different things.

**Modal**

```
<!-- MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="expenseModal_@expenseId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="expenseModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="expenseModalLabel"> Expences </h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div> <!-- MODEL HEADER-->
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div> <!-- MODAL BODY-->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addExpenses").click(function () {

            $(".modal-body").html('');

            $.ajax({

                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("_ExpenseForm", "Admin")',
                data: { type: $(this).attr("data-type") },
                success: function (response) {
                    $(".modal-body").html(response);
                    $("#expenseModal").modal('show');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Something went wrong");
                }

            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

The expense Id has to be inserted in the form so that when it is saved it saves it to the correct Expense report.

**Controller actions**

```
    ExpensesDataAcessLayer objexpense = new ExpensesDataAcessLayer();
    public ActionResult ExpenseReports()
    {
        return View(db.ExpenseReports.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult Expenses(int ExpenseId)
    {
        return View(db.Expenses.Where(x => x.ExpenseId == ExpenseId).ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult _ExpenseForm()
    {
        CustomerEntities customerEntities = new CustomerEntities();
        List<SelectListItem> categoryItem = new List<SelectListItem>();
        ExpensesViewModel casModel = new ExpensesViewModel();
        List<ExpenseTypes> expensetypes = customerEntities.ExpenseType.ToList();
        expensetypes.ForEach(x =>
        {
            categoryItem.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.CategoryItem, Value = x.ItemCategoryId.ToString() });
        });
        casModel.ExpenseTypes = categoryItem;

        return View(casModel);
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store `expenseId` into hidden field, like this

```
<input id="expenseId" name="expenseId" type="hidden" value="@Request.Url.Segments[3]">
```

Then you can get like this

```
 $("#addExpenses").click(function () {
var expenseId = $("#expenseId").val();
// after code here
```

**Updated**

You can get `expenseId` like this

```
var expenseId = $(this).attr("data-id")
```

Then you can assign it to hidden field or anywhere in `Model`, Like this

```
<!-adding aditional input into HTML in MODEL-!>
<input id="expenseId" name="expenseId" type="hidden" value="">

<!- Javascript-!>
var expenseId = $(this).attr("data-id")
expenseId.val(expenseId );
```

Comment: So i have that in my javascript but it is not in the ajax call to open the form in the modal. How do i get it to the modal form? Adding it to the url: doesnt work because it is not part of the ajax call.

Comment: You can try this way `data: { expenseId : $(this).attr("data-id") }`

Comment: I've updated my answer, please take a look @Scott Purtan

Comment: That actually worked. I added that and put a HiddenFor on the form. I am confused about how it is working. The hiddenFor does not have a value. It just puts it in the field...

Comment: You should manually get value when you submit the form. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520652/jquery-ajax-also-send-hidden-fields-on-form-change) was helpful for you.

Comment: I actually found that it is there because on the get action for the _ExpenseForm i had put this in place - public ActionResult _ExpenseForm(int ExpenseId) without it i do not receive the id.

Comment: Yes, it belongs to **How to pass param from `Ajax` into `Action Controller` in ASPNET MVC**. Basically, you've found the solution to `get` and `set` the `expenseId` value anywhere you want.